# Cannot output Laravel hasOne values in blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

In my model I have this

```
public function orderTotal():HasOne {
    return $this->HasOne(OrdersTotals::class)->where('class', 'ot_total');
}
```

If I output with the following

```
{{ $order->orderTotal }}
```

I get a string resembling JSON.

```
{"id":3,"order_id":2,"title":"Total","value":5980,"class":"ot_total","sort_order":300,"created_at":"2024-03-21T11:59:23.000000Z","updated_at":"2024-03-21T11:59:23.000000Z"}
```

It contains all of the data I need.  But I only want to display the index/key named "value"

So when I output with the following:

```
{{ $order->orderTotal->value }}
```

I get:

```
Attempt to read property "value" on null
```

When I output with the following:

```
{{ $order->orderTotal['value'] }}
```

I get

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

I've tried to reference the first index of the array with

```
{{ $order->orderTotal[0]->value }}
```

But I get

```
Undefined array key 0
```

If I try to output in a loop as follows:

```
@foreach ($order->orderTotal as $total)
    {{ $total }}
@endforeach
```

I get:

```
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
```

How am I supposed to properly reference that index/key to get its value??

If I change the relationship to hasMany

```
public function orderTotal():HasMany {
    return $this->HasMany(OrdersTotals::class)->where('class', 'ot_total');
}
```

And I loop through with

```
@foreach ($order->orderTotal as $total)
    {{ $total['value'] }}
@endforeach
```

I get the value but I don't understand why I have to use HasMany and loop through when the data is there with hasOne I just can't reference it.

Comment: Based on [Official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) `HasOne` is used to define a `one-to-one` relationship between 2 model classes. I see the first model being `OrderTotals`, is it a subclass of the `Order` model or standalone model?

Comment: I think the issue is you're looping over many **Orders** and some **Orders** might not have an **orderTotal** (`$order->orderTotal` equals `null`). Those orders are causing the error. You could use the null-safe operator to avoid getting the error `{{ $order->orderTotal?->value }}`

Comment: @IGP they all have an orderTotal and the data is there when I output `{{ $order->orderTotal }}` resembling a JSON string `{"id":3,"order_id":2,"title":"Total","value":5980,"class":"ot_total","sort_order":300,"created_at":"2024-03-21T11:59:23.000000Z","updated_at":"2024-03-21T11:59:23.000000Z"}`.  When I then try to access that data by defining my object further with `{{ $order->orderTotal->value }}`, I get `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`.  The question is how do I reference it

Comment: What gets outputted when you do `{{ get_class($order->orderTotal) }}`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `{{ $order->orderTotal?->value }}` you will probably find out that some orders do not have an orderTotal, and thus also not at value for orderTotal.